# SSH TOTP - Code confirmed but Failed keyboard-interactive/pam

Tags: ssh, pam, 2-factor-authentication

I am on Debian 12 and am trying to setup pam_google_authenticator.so for SSH 2fa with pubkey and TOTP.

I get through the setup with google-authenticator and put in the 2FA code that my token gives me, it suceeds. But logging in the password fails.

Setup:

```
$ google-authenticator 

Do you want authentication tokens to be time-based (y/n) y
Warning: pasting the following URL into your browser exposes the OTP secret to Google:
  https://www.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&chld=M|0&cht=qr&chl=otpauth://totp/itadmin@server01%3Fsecret%xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%26issuer%3Dserver01
                                                                    
Your new secret key is: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Enter code from app (-1 to skip): xxxxxx
Code confirmed
Your emergency scratch codes are:
  xxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx
  xxxxxxxx

Do you want me to update your "/home/itadmin/.google_authenticator" file? (y/n) y

Do you want to disallow multiple uses of the same authentication
token? This restricts you to one login about every 30s, but it increases
your chances to notice or even prevent man-in-the-middle attacks (y/n) y

By default, a new token is generated every 30 seconds by the mobile app.
In order to compensate for possible time-skew between the client and the server,
we allow an extra token before and after the current time. This allows for a
time skew of up to 30 seconds between authentication server and client. If you
experience problems with poor time synchronization, you can increase the window
from its default size of 3 permitted codes (one previous code, the current
code, the next code) to 17 permitted codes (the 8 previous codes, the current
code, and the 8 next codes). This will permit for a time skew of up to 4 minutes
between client and server.
Do you want to do so? (y/n) n

If the computer that you are logging into isn't hardened against brute-force
login attempts, you can enable rate-limiting for the authentication module.
By default, this limits attackers to no more than 3 login attempts every 30s.
Do you want to enable rate-limiting? (y/n) y
$ ls -lisa
total 28
783373 4 drwxr-xr-x 3 itadmin itadmin 4096 Aug  9 19:15 .
783364 4 drwxr-xr-x 4 root    root    4096 Aug  9 18:40 ..
783392 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 itadmin itadmin  220 Aug  4  2021 .bash_logout
783393 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 itadmin itadmin 1811 Aug  9 18:43 .bashrc
783396 4 -r-------- 1 itadmin itadmin  119 Aug  9 19:15 .google_authenticator
783391 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 itadmin itadmin  807 Aug  4  2021 .profile
783394 4 drwxr-xr-x 2 itadmin itadmin 4096 Aug  9 18:40 .ssh
```

I then make the modifications to sshd_config and pam sshd:

/etc/pam.d/sshd

```
# PAM configuration for the Secure Shell service

# Standard Un*x authentication.
@include common-auth

# Disallow non-root logins when /etc/nologin exists.
account    required     pam_nologin.so

# Uncomment and edit /etc/security/access.conf if you need to set complex
# access limits that are hard to express in sshd_config.
# account  required     pam_access.so

# Standard Un*x authorization.
@include common-account

# SELinux needs to be the first session rule.  This ensures that any
# lingering context has been cleared.  Without this it is possible that a
# module could execute code in the wrong domain.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so close

# Set the loginuid process attribute.
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Create a new session keyring.
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke

# Standard Un*x session setup and teardown.
@include common-session

# Print the message of the day upon successful login.
# This includes a dynamically generated part from /run/motd.dynamic
# and a static (admin-editable) part from /etc/motd.
session    optional     pam_motd.so  motd=/run/motd.dynamic
session    optional     pam_motd.so noupdate

# Print the status of the user's mailbox upon successful login.
session    optional     pam_mail.so standard noenv # [1]

# Set up user limits from /etc/security/limits.conf.
session    required     pam_limits.so

# Read environment variables from /etc/environment and
# /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session    required     pam_env.so # [1]
# In Debian 4.0 (etch), locale-related environment variables were moved to
# /etc/default/locale, so read that as well.
session    required     pam_env.so user_readenv=1 envfile=/etc/default/locale

# SELinux needs to intervene at login time to ensure that the process starts
# in the proper default security context.  Only sessions which are intended
# to run in the user's context should be run after this.
session [success=ok ignore=ignore module_unknown=ignore default=bad]        pam_selinux.so open

# 2FA TOTP Authentication
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so
```

/etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#General Options
Port 22
AddressFamily inet
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
#
#Crypto Options
KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com
#
#Authentication:
PermitRootLogin no
LoginGraceTime 2m
StrictModes yes
MaxAuthTries 3
MaxSessions 6
rekeylimit 500M 1h
#
#Other Auth Options
UsePAM yes
GSSAPIAuthentication no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
PermitEmptyPasswords no
#
#Key Authentication
AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
#
#MISC OPTIONS
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
PermitTunnel no
GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding no
PermitTTY yes
TCPKeepAlive no
PermitUserEnvironment no
Compression yes
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 3
UseDNS no
PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
MaxStartups 10:50:40
PrintLastLog no
PrintMotd no
VersionAddendum none
Banner none
DebianBanner no
#
#Chroot Options
#ChrootDirectory none
#
#Match Blocks
Match Address 192.168.0.2
        AllowUsers itadmin
```

But when sshing and putting in the current 2fa code the 'password' fails:

```
$ ssh server01
(itadmin@192.168.0.24) Password: 
(itadmin@192.168.0.24) Password: 
(itadmin@192.168.0.24) Password: 
Received disconnect from 192.168.0.24 port 22:2: Too many authentication failures
Disconnected from 192.168.0.24 port 22
$
```

SSH client config for reference :

```
Host server01
        Hostname 192.168.0.24
        User itadmin
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/servers.priv
        IdentitiesOnly yes
```

The 2fa code originally suceeded on the modules test, but now it fails on login?

Everything else works, when I comment out the `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive` line in `sshd_config` and restart the service, I can login just fine from the client.

Does the authentication module for pam read from the file in the users home directory when the user goes to login, or is that just a copy and the settings are actually stored somewhere else?

Whats wrong here??